# Format Data using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a data set something like this:

```
2,Black
2,Blue
2,Red
1,Small
1,Medium
```

I need to convert this into the following:

```
2_0
2_1
2_2
1_0
1_1
```

The LINQ query I have at the moment uses an index for the second number, however it doesn't reset to 0 when changing from 2_ to 1_.  I've tried using a GroupBy, but I can't get the results I need - can anyone help?

Comment: Do the `Black`,`Blue`,`Small`,`Medium` etc values actually map to integer values or are you expecting to somehow arbitrarily reset the index to zero when the primary identifier is different?

Comment: Show us the linq you do have. And the words, can we ignore those, they don't seem to affect the output. Remove them from question if so, explain what part they play if not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<string> output = input
    .GroupBy(i => i.Num)
    .SelectMany(grp => grp.Select((item, idx) => string.Format("{0}_{1}", grp.Key, idx)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group by the number and use the version of `Select()` that provides the index:

```
var result = data.GroupBy(x => x.Number,
                          (key, g) => g.Select((_, i) => string.Format("{0}_{1}", key, i)))
                 .SelectMany(x => x);
```

Note that this might behave differently than you'd expect if the same numbers aren't contiguous: e.g, `2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2`.

Comment: +1 - I didn't even know there was a version of `Select()` like that.  Which is exactly why I hang out here.